# How to draw a line by define it as being orthogonal to an axis and connect it to an intersection?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way to draw the blue line by defining it as perpendicular to the y axis and then connect it to the intersection?

Thanks for any help

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0) node [left] {0};

\draw [->](0,0)--(3.5,0) node[pos=.75,right,above]{};
\node [above] at (2.5,0){$m_l=0$};
       
\draw [->] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[above]{$y$};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (2,0);

\draw [dotted,black!75, name path=S1](0,-2) arc (-90:90:2);

\draw [->](0,0) -- (45:2) node [right] {$m_l=1$};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (-45:2) node [right] {$m_l=-1$};

\path [name path=yup] (0,0) -- (45:2.5);
\path [name path=ydown] (0,0) -- (45:2.5);

\draw [name intersections=
      {of=yup and S1, by=ml1}];
\draw [name intersections=
      {of=ydown and S1, by=ml-1}];

\draw [blue] (ml1) --  (0,{sqrt(2)});     

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand why what you already did doesn't suit you. Could you be more specific? Maybe with a sketch of the desired picture.

Comment: try `\draw [blue] (ml1) -|(A);`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to extract the y-coordinate from the coordinate `(ml1)`.

You can do this with the `let` command by adding the `calc` library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

Then the command

```
\draw [blue] let \p1=(ml1) in (\p1) --  (0,\y1);
```

will do what you want. Once `\p1` is assigned the coordinate `(ml1)`, the x- and y-coordinates are automtically assigned to `\x1` and `\y1`.